# Photoshop UI dialog return from function

Tags: javascript, function, user-interface, photoshop-script

How do I access the UI information (buttons pressed, slider values, radio buttons, text entered etc) from Photoshop UI dialog when it's a function?

I thought it would be in the form of `variable.ui_component.value`, but that only works from within the function as `dlg.ui_component.value`

```
var myReturn = dialog();

{
  var msg = myReturn.slider1.value;
  alert(msg);
}


function dialog()
{

    // DIALOG
    // ======
    var dlg = new Window("dialog"); 
        dlg.text = "Dialog"; 
        dlg.preferredSize.width = 120; 
        dlg.orientation = "column"; 
        dlg.alignChildren = ["center","top"]; 
        dlg.spacing = 10; 
        dlg.margins = 16; 

    var slider1 = dlg.add("slider", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, {name: "slider1"}); 
        slider1.minvalue = 0; 
        slider1.maxvalue = 100; 
        slider1.value = 50; 
        slider1.preferredSize.width = 80; 

    var button1 = dlg.add("button", undefined, undefined, {name: "button1"}); 
        button1.text = "OK"; 
        button1.preferredSize.width = 80; 

    var button2 = dlg.add("button", undefined, undefined, {name: "button2"}); 
        button2.text = "Cancel"; 
        button2.preferredSize.width = 80;

    // show the dialog;
    dlg.center();

    dlg.show();

    alert(slider1.value); // default = 50
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: `return dlg;` instead of `return dialog;` ?

Comment: however I usually just return only the things that are needed from the scriptUI function

Comment: It was `return dlg;`  :) Like you, I don't normally put UI into a function, but I just want to see if it was possible. Thanks

Comment: I got confused as you have to use the keyword `dialog`in a string to initiate the window `new Window("dialog");`